# Javascript popup with Exception details not appearing

Tags: c#, javascript, exception, popup

I have a try-catch block:

```
try{
//stuff here
}catch(Exception x){
    tran.Rollback();
    Response.Write("<script>alert('Error details: " + x + "');</script>");
    Response.Write("<script>alert('Error');</script>");
}
```

The "Error" message will popup, but the "Error details" won't. What am I missing? I've tried x.ToString(), x.Message...nothing...

Comment: I saw only the 'Error' message...the first message didnt popup at all, which I want to display the error details~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want serialize the string you're putting in to that script.

```
try 
{

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    String jsSafeString = ser.Serialize(ex.Message);
    // use this string in your script.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the message to be print on the page, just get the **Message** property of the exception class

```
try{
//stuff here
}catch(Exception x){
tran.Rollback();
Response.Write("<script>alert('Error details: " + x.Message + "');</script>");
Response.Write("<script>alert('Error');</script>");
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`cleanMessage` is your `exception string`.

```
string script = string.Format("alert('{0}');", cleanMessage);
if (page != null && !page.ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered("alert")) 
{
    page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(page.GetType(), "alert", script, true /* addScriptTags */);
}
```

Comment: No dice...I assume page is this.Page?